# How to create in yii2 dropdownlist submenu?

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, yii2, html-select

I have a problem with yii2 field class dropdownlist submenu?
How to create in dropdownlist submenu or subselect list.[image]
[image: my form]

my db scheme

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| group_name   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| short_name   | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_group | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| admin_group  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

in data

```
+----+------------------------------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| id | group_name                         | short_name | parent_group | admin_group |
+----+------------------------------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | Jizzax Davlat Pedagogika instituti | JDPI       |         NULL |        NULL |
|  2 | O'quv ishlari bo'yicha Prorektor   | Prorektor  |            1 |        NULL |
|  3 | Axborot tehnologiyalari markazi    | ATM        |            2 |        NULL |
+----+------------------------------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

i use short_name and echo select i see :

```
-JDPI 
--Prorektor
---ATM
```

Comment: for what purpose you want to use it? is it for navigation?

Comment: use get id select item

Comment: I think you should use dependent dropdown structure

Comment: Update your question and add the related  code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method to the model class

```
public static function getItems($indent = '', $parent_group = null)
{
    $items = [];
    // for all childs of $parent_group (roots if $parent_group == null)
    $groups = self::find()->where(['parent_group'=>$parent_group])
        ->orderBy('short_name')->all();
    foreach($groups as $group)
    {
        // add group to items list 
        $items[$group->id] = $indent.$group->short_name;
        // recursively add children to the list with indent
        $items = array_merge($items, self::getItems($indent.' ', $group->id));
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Method output should be

```
[
    1 => 'JDPI',
    2 => ' Prorektor',
    3 => '  ATM'
]
```

In view

```
echo $form->field($model, 'group_id')->dropDownList(YourModelClass::getItems());
```

where YourModelClass is your model class name.

I recomend to use nested sets to store tree information.There are some extensions for nested sets:

- Behavior https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets
- Input widget http://demos.krajee.com/tree-manager